How can I make these two animations work at the same time?
Trying to make these animations work, but only one works at a time. What am I doing wrong?
If I delete one the other works and vice versa.
using tailwind css
class="animate-down"
class="animate-shake"

animation: {
  'down': 'down 2s ease-in-out infinite',
},
keyframes: {
  'down' : {
    '0%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '1%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '2%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '3%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '5%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '6%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '7%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '8%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '9%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '10%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0)' },
    '11%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 0px)' },
    '100%' : { transform: 'translate(0, 20px)' },
  },
},

animation: {
  'shake': 'shake 3s ease-in-out infinite',
},
keyframes: {
  'shake' : {
    '0%' : { transform: 'rotate(0deg)' },
    '1%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg)' },
    '2%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg)' },
    '3%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg)' },
    '5%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg)' },
    '6%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg)' },
    '7%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg)' },
    '8%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg)' },
    '9%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg)' },
    '10%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg)' },
    '11%' : { transform: 'rotate(0deg)' },
    '100%' : { transform: 'rotate(0deg)' },
  },
},


They both work but one at a time only.

Needs more code and context

add a working code snippet

transform is one CSS property; you can not assign it values in two different places, and then expect that those would somehow "combine". You will need to combine both keyframes into a single one, specifying both the translate and the rotate values for transform.

Or you introduce an additional wrapper element - so that you can apply one specific transformation to the wrapper, and the other to the child element within it.

Or use the new(ish) property translate on one an transform; rotate on the other?

Assuming both these CSS classes(animate-down and animate-shake) are being applied to the same HTML element.
Since both the keyframes use the transform property, either of the two is supposed to work.
Alternatively you can combine the 2 keyframes for both the animations to work together.
keyframes: {
  'down_n_shake' : {
        '0%' : { transform: 'rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '1%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '2%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '3%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '5%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '6%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '7%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '8%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '9%' : { transform: 'rotate(20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '10%' : { transform: 'rotate(-20deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '11%' : { transform: 'rotate(0deg) translate(0, 0)' },
        '100%' : { transform: 'rotate(0deg) translate(0, 20px)' 
        },
      },
    },

